# Limit of a sequence. Alternative definition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, definition

Normally we use the following definition for a limit of a sequence:
We consider L to be the limit of a sequence an iff:

$$\forall \ \epsilon>0 \ \exists \  N  \ \forall n \geq N: |a_n−L| \leq \epsilon$$

Could you please elaborate if we could have the following definition?:

$$\forall \ N \ \exists \  \epsilon>0  \ \forall n \geq N: |a_n−L| \leq \epsilon $$

(the same as above, but N and ϵ switch places).

To my mind, this definition would also provide a concept for a sequence coming close to a limit $L$ but would be in some sense more strict (the sequence would have to start converging from the first element, but not starting from some N as in original definition).

Am I right?

Comment: With this definition any bounded sequence would converge to any number...

Comment: Please use MathJax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really think the definition of limit as a game between you and someone that tries to convince the skeptical you that $a_n\rightarrow L$. To play the game, you pick an $\epsilon$, and your opponent will give you a $N$ such that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. So unless you can come up with a particular $\epsilon$ that your opponent fails to demonstrate the existence of $N$, he/she will always be able to convince you. That is, you set up the standard of how close you want the sequence to be to $L$, and your opponent tells you how far down $n$ has to go toward $\infty$ to satisfy you.

In your definition, you are playing a very different game: You pick $N$, and your opponent show you there is an $\epsilon$. He/she actually has a very easy winning stragety if $\{a_n\}$ is bounded by $B$: No matter what your $N$ is, he/she will just say "I pick $\epsilon=B+|L|$", then $|a_n-L|\le |a_n| + |L| \le B + |L|$. In spirit, when you are coming up with $\epsilon$, you want to make it smaller to maker your opponet's life harder, but your opponent will come up with big $\epsilon$ to make his/her life easier.

Comment: No for all real cases: e−1x2 is smooth and real analytic over R−{0}. For the complex case, as you mentioned, it's the problem of whether an isolated singularity is removable. One equivalent condition for an isolated signularity is removable is that f(z) is bounded around z0, and the proof is simple: The residue around z0 must be 0 by integrating over circles that shrinks to z0, from here conclude that ∮γf(z)dz=0 for any closed γ, and then apply the Morera's theorem. This avoids using power series or Laurent series.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit intricate as a definition. When we say that a sequence converges we mean that
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : |a_n-L| < \varepsilon
$$
This means that for $\textit{any choice of epsilon}$, we may pick a corresponding natural number $N$ such that all sequence terms with $n \geq N$ are epsilon close to $L$.

However think of what you are proposing,
$$
\forall N > 0, \exists \varepsilon > 0 : \forall n\geq N:|a_n-L| < \varepsilon
$$
This means that for any choice of natural number, we would be able to find a particular epsilon such that for all $n \geq N$ we have $|a_n-L| < \varepsilon$. But when we want the sequence to converge, do we want to be picking particular epsilon's for select tail-sequences of $(a_n)$?